# JIRA Cloud API GET Request - Works in Postman, but not Powershell

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

I am able to perform a GET Request from Jira successfully in Postman, but am unable to make the same request in Powershell due to an authentication error. I know that my credentials are correct because there are or GET Requests that are successful. My guess is that it has something to do with the URL (https://arnold.jira.com**/admin/rest/um/1/user**).

Since I know that my credentials are correct, I am not sure what else I can try.

```
# Create a new session using the Jira REST API

$user = 'john.rambo@arnold.com'
$pass = '8675309'
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$Headers = @{
 Authorization = $basicAuthValue;
 Accept = 'application/json'
}

# Perform the GET Request 

$UserEmail = 'dolf.lundgren@arnold.com'
$UserAttributeLink = 'https://arnold.jira.com/admin/rest/um/1/user?email=' + $UserEmail + '&expand=attributes'
$UserAttributes = Invoke-RestMethod ($UserAttributeLink) -Headers $Headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

I expect to have the info returned, but am met with this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : User failed to authenticate
At line:12 char:19
+ ... ttributes = Invoke-RestMethod ($UserAttributeLink) -Headers $Headers  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: GET, Reques\u2026PowerShell/6.2.1
}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-RestMethod], HttpResponseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you add `-UseBasicParsing` to the `Invoke-RestMethod` call?

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Yes I do.

Comment: Never mind.. that parameter doesn't do anything anyway.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy No worries, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: According to [the Atlassian site](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/), using passwords with Basic authentication is actively being disabled.  Have you tried using an API token in place of the password?

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Yes, that is what I have set. It works for all other GET/POST calls I have but this one.

Comment: Try `DisableStrictNameChecking` in Windows. https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/01/21/401-unauthorized-browsing-site-from-local-iis-instance/